# CheckBox in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

i have two options

One

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("postType", false, new { @id = item.int_PostTypeId.ToString() })%>
```

Second

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="postType" value="<%= item.int_PostTypeId.ToString() %>
```

1st question:
what is differenct between these two method of check box declaration.

2nd question:
and how can we get value of checked checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Html.Checkbox (or even better the CheckBoxFor, in MVC2) if you use a model binder. It will handle the checkbox transparently to you, and you will read the boolean value on your model. It will render something more complicated than a checkbox (to avoid the problem which arises from the fact that an unchecked checkbox is not transmitted at all in a POST).

On the contrary, use the input if you retrieve the value via FormCollection: if you use the Html.Checkbox compound, you will receive something "strange" in the post (not the usual value, but a string with two testual values (like "true,false").  If you use the input, you just have to check if there exists that name in the post keys.

Answer (score 0):

One major difference is that your are setting the "id" attribute of the HTML input (@ is used to denote the HTML tag attribute: @id, @class, etc.) in the first snippet and setting the "value" of the second...

You need to set the @id in both, so that you can retrieve the value easily in Javascript.

You didn't say in what context you wanted the value - whether client side via javascript or controller side via .NET.

Comment: your answer is not meaningful.

Comment: @Xulfee.  I answered question 1 and asked a follow up question to question 2... It's not polite to lower my answer when my response was correct and to the point.