# MVC: To-do list checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm developing an app in ASP.NET MVC, and part of it is a to-do list. The image url below shows how it looks and works so far:

[image: Tasks]

What I'd like to accomplish is instead of it displaying true or false for 'completed', i'd like to display a check box which can be checked and then changes the value to true or false in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use this html helper to display a checkbox:

```
Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.yourBooleanField)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will this change the value in the database at all? Or does that require additional code?

Comment: You will get the value in your model in the controller method called on submit. After that, you can save it as you want.
BTW, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826554/checkbox-in-asp-net-mvc)  might be helpful for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a beginner at MVC so is there any chance you could explain this in a bit more detail? It's much appreciated. (That link seems useful but didn't help me fix the problem)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to explain it in detail here (i'm at work ^^), but you can go there to find useful doc:
http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/matthijs/aspnet-mvc-2-basics-introduction-by-scott-hanselman
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc-part1
http://www.asp.net/mvc/fundamentals
And Professional ASP.NET MVC 2 is a great book.